# How can I center a div with a centered image inside a div?

Tags: css, html, centering

I want to have an image centered within each DIV that is floating left within a larger DIV.

In the following example, I want the gray boxes ("assetInfoBody") to be centered within the green boxes ("assetBox"). What else can I try here beside text-align:center and margin:auto?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #assets {
                background-color: orange;
                padding: 5px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            .assetbox {
                background-color: lightgreen;
                float: left;
                width: 100px;
                margin-right: 5px;
                            text-align: center;
            }

            .assetInfoBody {
                background-color: grey;
                position: relative;
                width: 80px;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .centeredItem {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                top: 0px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="assets">
            <div class="assetbox">
                <div class="assetInfoBody">
                    <div class="centeredItem">
                        <img src="images/box.png"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="assetbox">
                <div class="assetInfoBody">
                    <div class="centeredItem">
                        <img src="images/box.png"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="assetbox">
                <div class="assetInfoBody">
                    <div class="centeredItem">
                        <img src="images/box.png"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: without being a css expert, i see you  have margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; in centeredItem.
If you copy/paste it in assetInfoBody, this doesn't work? Just asking.

Comment: actually you are right in the above example, the problem is that we now need assetInfoBody to be absolute to match the HTML that this example needs to be built into, since rounded-corners made from graphics are being applied to it, so it has become a slightly different problem, but thanks for the clarity on this

Answer (score 1):

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/JY4eN/1/) for a reference to how you could achieve this. As your class `.assetInfoBody` class has a set width you can align the `.centeredItem` by applying the rule `margin:0 auto` to it. By also applying `text-align:center` to `.centeredItem` you're able to always keep the image centered within it.

Answer (score 0):

probably you want a css like that:

```
#assets {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
.assetbox {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.assetInfoBody {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  width: 80px;
}

.centeredItem {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```